# axios patch updates website state, but it doesnt update mongo db state

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js, axios, mongodb-atlas

I have been trying to edit/update product on my website trough axios patch method. When i submit my form i get status 200 OK , and data on the website is updated, until i refresh the page. When i refresh it old values return and db is not updated, which means that there is a problem with communication with db.

I am using atlas mongodb, and i had similar problem with axios delete method, but the problem was in Atlas IP restrictions which i have solved now, but problem with axios patch remains.

my vuejs patch method:

```
handleEditForm(_id) {
      axios.patch(`http://localhost:3000/api/ropes/${_id}`, this.ropes)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            this.showModal = false

          }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })

    },

  }
```

server side patch:

```
router.patch('/:ropeId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updatedRope = await Rope.updateOne({_id: req.params.ropeId}, {
            $set: {
                image:req.body.image,
                title: req.body.title,
                description: req.body.description,
                diameter:req.body.diameter,
                price:req.body.price,
                cartQuantity:req.body.cartQuantity,
                totalQuantity:req.body.totalQuantity

            }
        })
        res.json(updatedRope)
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err})
    }
})
```

console log:

```
adapter: function xhrAdapter(config)
​​
data: "[{\"_id\":\"60171a1bd86adc454b3b757a\",\"title\":\"Polyester sinking ropes\",\"description\":\"Polyester sinking rope Polyester sinking rope Polyester sinking rope Polyester sinking rope Polyester sinking rope\",\"image\":\"\",\"diameter\":\"22mm\",\"price\":35,\"cartQuantity\":1,\"totalQuantity\":\"1000\",\"date\":\"2021-01-31T20:59:07.452Z\",\"__v\":0}]"
​​
Object { data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }

headers: Object { Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" }
​​
maxBodyLength: -1
​​
maxContentLength: -1
​​
method: "patch"
​​
timeout: 0
``
```

Comment: In your function .then() what does console.log(res) display in your console? the route doesn't seem to have anything wrong with it

Comment: It Says: ` Object { data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
RopeCrud.vue:86
`

Comment: And what is inside data array inside that res

Comment: Also inside your route do a console.log(req.params.ropeId) to see if the Id is actually being passed

Comment: i have updated question with console.log(res)

Comment: when i do a Postman patch from my route it updates db normally ...

Comment: Ok so the server is good in that case, last thing I can think of is maybe try  handleEditForm(ropeId) and in your URL ${ropeId} instead of _id

Comment: i get same result in the console :(

Comment: I think the issue is to do with ropeId, so maybe try console.log(req.params.ropeId) in your route and see if its null or undefined

Comment: it displays Id normally in the console... so that's not the problem